# .net core retrieve controller name and action name from HttpContext

Tags: asp.net-core

in a middleware trying to get controller name and action by code below;

```
private SystemLog CreateRequestLogEntity(HttpContext context)
        {
            var _logEntity = new SystemLog();
            if (context.Request.Path.HasValue)
            {
                string _uri = context.Request.Path.ToUriComponent();
                string[] arrs = _uri.Split('/');
                if (arrs.Length >= 1)
                    _logEntity.controller = arrs[1];
                if (arrs.Length >= 2)
                    _logEntity.action = arrs[2];
            }
```

works fine for simple requests but as you see its risky and extremely ugly,

how to make it properly?

Answer (score 8):

Try the code as follow:

```
   private void CreateRequestLogEntity(HttpContext context)
    {
        string controllerName = context.Request.RouteValues["controller"].ToString();
        string actionName = context.Request.RouteValues["action"].ToString();
        // do other things
    }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like this:

```
context.GetRouteValue("controller").ToString();
```